# Does R-Programming language have this syntax?

Tags: math, identify

I was given the following code to analyze and understand what it does. My challenge is that i don't even know what programming language was used to write the code.

Here's a snippet of the code:

`**REGOPT** (PVCALC, PVPRINT, STARS);
    SET NN = 100; SET X12 = 0.99; SET TT =0;
    SET RR = 50; SET SE = 10;
    SET B0 = 14; SET B1 = 5; SET B2 = 2; SET B3 = 6; 
    MMAKE B B0 B1 B2 B3;
    SET NOLS = 0; SET NGRM = 0; SET = NORKH =0; SET NMARM0 =0;
    SET NMARM1 = 0; SET NMARM2 = 0; SET NMARM3 = 0; SET NMARM4 = 0;
    SET NMARM5 = 0;
    SET NMARM6 = 0; SET NMARM7 = 0; SET NMARM8 = 0; SET NMARM9 = 0;`

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful: http://www.nber.org/tsp/tsphelp/regopt.htm

Comment: I think that @SlitCanvas is correct. [The reference manual](http://www.nber.org/tsp/tsp50rm.pdf) has entries for both `SET` and `MMAKE`. Unfortunately, the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TSP_(econometrics_software)) on TSP contains a dead link and gives the impression that it isn't being actively maintained anymore.